# How should I display procedure in "monitor" in netlogo?

Tags: plot, simulation, netlogo, monitor

I am working on traffic simulation in netlogo. I have written method of `calculate-travel-time`. I want to display this method in MONITOR control as well as in plot. I am unable to show the output of this method. I want help regarding this. Following is code:

```
   set travel-time (ticks - birth-tick) / 950
  ifelse avg = 0
  [
   set avg travel-time
  ]
  [
    set avg ((19 * avg + travel-time) / 20)
  ]

  die
end
```

Comment: This snippet doesn't make a lot of sense. Please show the whole procedure. Is the variable 'avg' a global variable, or a turtle attribute or what?

Comment: Yes, I agree with JenB.  You need to show the whole procedure and if you can, explain what error you get when you try to show the output.  If you're trying to compute and store an exponentially smoothed average of past travel times, and that's an attribute of whatever turtle is calling this routine, then you don't want a "die" statement immediately after you set the value, or it will always end up zero.